# ORM, Symfony без аннотаций

Tags: php, symfony, orm

Изучаю symfony 4, дико раздражает, что аннотации несут исполняющий код/надстройку. На сайте symfony не нашел инфы как работать с ORM без аннотаций, например вот код:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $price;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrice(): ?int
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function setPrice(int $price): self
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Как по мне вообще не читабельно, как разобраться, есть ли способ их не использовать как например с маршрутами, для них есть отдельный файл. Если без них некуда, где найти вменяемую документацию, где будет описано, что делают аннотации

```
/**

 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
```

с переменной `$id`. Сейчас в процессе обучения, все это создаю через консоль командами, там автогенерация всего этого, меня это просто ох**ть как бесит. Поделитесь кто разрабатывает на `Symfony`, какие есть варианты? кроме учить вместо него `Lavarel`?

Answer (score 2):

Обычно держу конфиги в yaml
Достаточно разместить в подпапке проекта Resources/config/doctrine/ файл <имя сущности>.orm.yml - он подхватится автоматически. (либо доконфигурить свой путь в настройках доктрины)
Все конфиги на сайте Симфони даются в трех вариантах: аннотации, yaml, xml
Напр. про маппинг

`App\Entity\Product:
    type: entity
    # ...
    manyToOne:
        category:
            targetEntity: App\Entity\Category
            inversedBy: products
            joinColumn:
                nullable: false`

Также можно описывать роутинг, валидацию и т.д.
https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/bundles/configuration.html

Comment: Можете дополнить свой ответ большим примером? Там где описаны поля и тд, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Соглашусь, аннотации не супер удобно, но тут все на любителя. Я использую маппинги. Для примера:

config/packages/doctrine.yaml:

```
parameters:
    # Adds a fallback DATABASE_URL if the env var is not set.
    # This allows you to run cache:warmup even if your
    # environment variables are not available yet.
    # You should not need to change this value.
    env(DATABASE_URL): ''

doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        driver: 'pdo_mysql'
        server_version: '5.7'
        charset: utf8mb4
        default_table_options:
            charset: utf8mb4
            collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        types:
            carbondatetime: DoctrineExtensions\Types\CarbonDateTimeType
            date: DoctrineExtensions\Types\CarbonDateType
            time: DoctrineExtensions\Types\CarbonTimeType

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: yml
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Mappings'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
```

Mappings/User.orm.yml:

```
App\Entity\User:
  type: entity
  id:
    userId:
      type: guid

  fields:
    username:
      type: string
      length: 191
      unique: true
    email:
      type: string
      length: 191
      unique: true
    password:
      type: text
    lastLogin:
      type: carbondatetime
      nullable: true
    createdAt:
      type: carbondatetime
      nullable: true
    updatedAt:
      type: carbondatetime
      nullable: true
```

Entity/User.php:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Entity;

    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;

    /**
     * Class User
     * @package App\Entity
     */
    class User
    {
        /**
         * @var string
         */
        private $userId;

        /**
         * @var string
         */
        private $username;

        /**
         * @var string
         */
        private $email;

        /**
         * @var string
         */
        private $password;

        /**
         * @var Carbon
         */
        protected $createdAt;

        /**
         * @var Carbon
         */
        protected $updatedAt;

        /**
         * @var Carbon
         */
        private $lastLogin;

        /**
         * User constructor.
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->userId = Uuid::uuid4();
            $this->createdAt = Carbon::now();
            $this->updatedAt = Carbon::now();
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getUserId(): string
        {
            return $this->userId;
        }

        /**
         * @return Carbon
         */
        public function getCreatedAt(): Carbon
        {
            return $this->createdAt;
        }

        /**
         * @return Carbon
         */
        public function getUpdatedAt(): Carbon
        {
            return $this->updatedAt;
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getUsername(): string
        {
            return $this->username;
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getEmail(): string
        {
            return $this->email;
        }

        /**
         * @return string
         */
        public function getPassword(): string
        {
            return $this->password;
        }

        /**
         * @param string $username
         *
         * @return User
         */
        public function setUsername(string $username): User
        {
            $this->username = $username;
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * @param string $email
         *
         * @return User
         */
        public function setEmail(string $email): User
        {
            $this->email = $email;
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * @param string $password
         *
         * @return User
         */
        public function setPassword(string $password): User
        {
            $this->password = $password;
            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * @return Carbon
         */
        public function getLastLogin(): Carbon
        {
            return $this->lastLogin;
        }

        /**
         * @return User
         */
        public function setLastLogin(): User
        {
            $this->lastLogin = Carbon::now();
            return $this;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Аннотации над свойствами и методами, это ведь не просто коммент, они указывают на типизацию и/или на тип возвращаемого значения?

Comment: @Winteriscoming В моем случае, это просто комментарии, для IDE

Comment: Можете пожалуйста объяснить что тут происходит `type: entity
  id:
    userId:
      type: guid`

Comment: Первичный ключ указывается? А когда внешний надо, тоже так же или просто как поле?

Comment: Можете еще и контроллер показать пожалуйста

Comment: @Winteriscoming контроллер у меня это сервис, с параметром репозатория

Comment: Подскажите, как быть если надо createQueryBuilder? Как вы делаете join?

Comment: @Winteriscoming [отличный туториал](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/doctrine/associations.html)